# nas4free server can't access local network

Tags: networking, freebsd, freenas

I'm trying to configure an old desktop machine as a NAS device with nas4free. I followed the [setup and user guide](http://wiki.nas4free.org/doku.php?id=documentation:setup_and_user_guide) to install nas4free on the primary HDD, configure network, and configure IP address.

I'm using DHCP to acquire an IP address, which works. It gets an IP of 192.168.1.107, which is an address in a valid range for my LAN. However, using the ping tool in the menu (and the ping command from the shell), pinging anything other than 192.168.1.107 times out (google.com, my gateway IP, other machines on the LAN by name and IP). Pinging the nas4free server from other machines on my network also time out.

So the network stuff seems to work enough to get an IP address but nothing else ... how can I diagnose this issue?

Comment: What does `iptables -L -n` show?

Comment: `iptables: Command not found`

Comment: Well, I gave up and installed the Ubuntu server 12 package. No networking problems there.